# Java functional interfaces weird "potentially ambiguous" warning

Tags: java, compiler-warnings, functional-interface

Can someone understand why `javac` raises this warning below?

```
warning: [overloads]
simpleString(String,Function<Settings,String>,Function<String,String>,Property...) in Setting
is potentially ambiguous with
simpleString(String,Validator<String>,Property...) in Setting
```

`Validator` is a basic class defined as below.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Validator<T> {
    void validate(T value);
}
```

These two API don't even have the same number of functional interface parameters.

Thanks

Comment: It can potentially be ambiguous, but for one, only if `Function` is congruent with `Validator` (after type erasure). Your specified `Validator` is **not** congruent with `java.util.function.Function`, so the actual classes used must be some different classes than you think.

Comment: It would help if you'd provide a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet unfortunately I can't reproduce it in a MVC example (see Gist below), but the error message doesn't make sense to me as the number functional parameters aren't the same.

https://gist.github.com/cbismuth/5e06685f28ba893f2914e74d49607ced

Comment: That would suggest you're not looking at the code you think you're looking at - either because it's out of date with what the compiler's using (or vice versa), or because you're looking at a similarly-named-but-different class somehow, like Mark suggested. I don't think anyone will be able to help you solve this if you can't reproduce it.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus that's what I also think ...

Comment: The code you linked to compiles for me - it's not clear whether it compiles for you as well or not.

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet, I'll have a look to automatically added imports and clean Gradle cache, you're probably right.

Comment: @JonSkeet the code compiles with a warning and "-Werror" makes the build fail. But I don't think there should even be a warning.

Comment: @ChristopheBismuth check your java compiler version too, it might have a role

Comment: @GPI yes thank you, I'm on Java 11.

Comment: Could be a regression (i.e. javac bug). I don't have Java 11 to test.

Comment: I just created an empty java project with openJDK 11.0.1, and the gist compiles

Comment: Thank you @GPI, I also tried, and it compiles. I've checked imports, they're right. I just don't understand this warning.

Comment: What is `Property`?